# How to retrieve header response with ajax in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, header

Is this layer accessible for ajax?

Answer (score 3):

The ajax code gives you access to the XMLHttpRequest object, which has APIs ("getResponseHeader") to check header elements.

Specifically, the first argument to the "complete" callback is the "xhr" object.

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  complete: function(xhr, status) {
    if (xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Hi-Stackoverflow")) {
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```